# HostingEnvironment.MapPath issue asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I trying to host an asp.net mvc (3.0) app (discountasp.net) which works fine locally but when I run it on the host's server I get:

Could not find a part of the path 'E:\web\bladibla\htdocs\xyz\in_e14095d9-59be-4f46-acff-b0125727ed9f'.

I am using:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("/xyz")) + "/";
```

to determine the folder on the server which exists. My program has to write and read some tmep files into this folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
Server.MapPath("~/xyz") + "/";
```

if xyz is a folder at the root of your application.

Comment: Problem is that I do this in the service layer not in the 'web layer'. I think I can shift the http context or something ... still the question remains why does it work on the development machine and not on the deployment one.

Comment: I tried Server.MapPath as well. It produces a decent path but I still get: Could not find a part of the path ...

Comment: OOps the server's folder name was wrong. Both methods work fine. The advantage of HostingEnvironment.MapPath is that you do not need the httpcontext. Thanks.